# Assign class to nth tr

Tags: jquery, html

I have table with several tr. I am finding solve where for first `<tr>` assign `class='alt'`, for next `<tr>` `class='alt-2'` and for third row `class='alt-3'` using jQuery. If table has got many rows I want to this script repeat. Please do you know some a solution by jQuery? 
Thanks

```
<table id="news">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Headline</th>
        <th id="autor">Author</th>
        <th>Topic</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">2011</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Apr 15</td>
        <td>jQuery 1.6 Beta 1 Released</td>
        <td>John Resig</td>
        <td>Releases</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Feb 24</td>
        <td>jQuery Conference 2011: San Francisco Bay Area</td>
        <td>Ralph Whitbeck</td>
        <td>Conferences</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Feb 7</td>
        <td>New Releases, Videos &amp; a Sneak Peek at the jQuery UI Grid</td>
        <td>Addy Osmani</td>
        <td>Plugins</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: show us the jquery that you have tried so far...

Comment: What's wrong with just using `nth-child`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to target all `tr`s including the one in the `thead` else use `:nth-child`

```
$('#news tr').addClass(function (idx) {
    var rem = idx % 3;
    return 'alt' + (rem == 0 ? '' :'-'+ (rem + 1))
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8PpNp/)

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u5N9S/1/)

```
var i = 1;
$("#news tbody tr").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass('alt-' + i);
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include all `tr` :

```
$('#news tr').each(function(i, z){
  $(this).addClass('alt' + (i == 0 ? '' : '-' + (i + 1)));
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5SCp2/3/)

OR If only want to include tr inside `tbody`

```
$('#news tbody tr').each(function(i, z){
      $(this).addClass('alt' + (i == 0 ? '' : '-' + (i + 1)));
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5SCp2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
$("#news tr").addClass(function (idx) {
    if(idx != 1){
        return (idx!= 0) ? "alt-" + idx : "alt";
    }
});
```